# C# Queue or ServiceBus with no dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, queue, servicebus

Is there a product (ideally open source, but not necessary), that would enable a zero dependency deployment?  every service bus or queue library I've been able to find has a dependency on one of the queue apps (like msmq), or a database.  I would like a very lightweight solution that I can just add a reference to my application, build it, and deploy it with as little configuration as possible.

In an ideal world, the queue/service bus would run on IIS, and allow web and rich clients to talk to it.

Such a tool would be ideal for fast prototyping of large distributed systems on a local development machine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rhino Queues from Ayende is exactly what you are looking for, this is the blog post introducing it:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/01/Rhino-Queues.aspx

I think that all of the limitations mentioned in this post have been fixed since then.

From the blog post, what rhino queues is:

- XCopyable, Zero Administration, Embedded, Async queuing service
- Robust in the face of networking outages
- System.Transactions support
- Fast
- Works over HTTP

Comment: THis is no good... if the server restarts, the queue items in memory are all gone

Comment: @user1034912 - this is not the case; message are persisted in a local esent database. I think this wasn't the case yet at the time the blog post was written.

Answer (score 5):

In a similar vein to ShuggyCoUk's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/546328/3195477), you could rig up a queue (or queues) using the Windows built-in ESENT database (comes already installed with Windows).  There is a managed code access library (open source): http://www.codeplex.com/ManagedEsent.  If you stick with writing / reading CLOBs or BLOBs, it should work just fine.  If you want to be really clever, you can use [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com) and write (contribute?) ESENT-flavored subscription storage and transports.  There are some forays into using ESENT on [Ayende's blog](http://www.ayende.com) as well (you'll have to poke around his SVN repository for the juicy bits).

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to be:

1. Windows specific
2. Limited to the local domain
3. Seriously limited in the message size supported
4. Wrap the underlying win32 calls in P/Invoke
5. Deal with the polling yourself
6. Deal with the hacks needed to allow back and forth communication
7. Deal with the shared config needed to keep the names in sync

Then a quick wrapper around the windows [MailSlot API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365576(VS.85).aspx) might be sufficient.

This [simple example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/dparys/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=137) is a reasonable basis to start.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/CSharp_MailSlots.aspx) has some further information but assumes the use case is via a control (rather than a Component as it should be) as well as some poor WinForms integration so should be considered for incidental reading rather than a basis for any library.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/mailslots.aspx) is C++ but is of a higher standard (and a commenter has extended it to support the batching of larger messages into several smaller ones).

You get 424 bytes (so with .Net 212 chars) you may want to drop to ASCII to double your useful message length if you are talking text.

Note that despite its simplicity, limitations and lack of features it does provide multicast delivery, something often complex to layer on a point to point protocol yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This [ayende post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/18/subscriptions-mass-transit-vs.-nservicebus-vs.-rhino-servicebus.aspx) provides and interesting comparison of three service buses.  We use [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/) and think if it's not clear that [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com/) would respond to how you'd plug in non-dependent queue.

We work using MSMQ happily but there are other options and in theory it should be open to practically anything, given that you may lose some reliability and durability depending on your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Why not [Amazon's](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) message service Simple Queue Service?

Comment: That definitely adds significant network latency considerations

Answer (score 1):

We moved our projects from MSMQ to [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/). its really better :)
ActiveMQ is **open source** queue ,based on Apache web server.
We used him in production on high frequently data workflow, where msmq have a lot of problem (we work with msmq a year)
The csharp implementation is [nms](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on an open source WCF based service bus. You can find it here: http://rockbus.codeplex.com/. It supports dynamic (@run-time) subscriptions, subcription repository (database), pluggable transports, XPath based content-based routing, transactional delivery over wcf protocols, roundrobin delivery, pluggable subscription evaluation, and more. Have a look!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a service like IronMQ by http://Iron.io?

You wouldn't have any dependencies,  could quickly prototype apps without setting up any queue infrastructure, and it's highly available and fast.

There is not currently a locally installable version but it's based on the upcoming OpenStack protocol so there will be.

Btw I work for Iron.

Comment: Hi, Chad; thanks for the answer! I would like to point out that all of your recent posts have been advertisements for your company's products. It's OK to have an occasional post that mentions your products, but it seems like the only reason you are here is for promotion. This can lead to your posts being flagged as spam or even your account being deleted, along with the posts. Please consider answering questions about coding to help other programmers, and not so much on just promoting your company's products.

Comment: Sure Andrew, thanks for the tip. I'm just mentioning the products where it makes sense. I'll continue to advise on architecture and other options as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/mcintyre321/PieQ - this is my attempt to write a threadsafe, persistent, zero-config, embedded work queue. It probably needs a little love, but I think it might be the kind of tool you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an InMemory JMS library which can be used to in testing JMS applications without really connecting to JMS providers/server (Think of hsqldb). You don't have to deal with connection or protocol or anything, all you need to do is to send and receive messages.

https://github.com/Dhana-Krishnasamy/InMemoryJMS